# How to make a batch input in FB02 by updating the xref2 field

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I would like an example of how to make a batch input in `FB02` transaction code by updating the `xref2` field?

I tried updating the table directly in the table `BKPF`.

I need example how make with this change specific field

You could help me have a solution for this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get batch input codes via SAP GUI. Go to System > Service > Batch input > Recorder and start new recording.

| Program | Scr | SID | Field name | Field value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | T | FB02 |  |
| SAPMF05L | 0100 | X |  |  |
|  |  |  | BDC_CURSOR | RF05L-BELNR |
|  |  |  | BDC_OKCODE | =WEITE |
|  |  |  | RF05L-BELNR | 5000000001 |
|  |  |  | RF05L-BUKRS | 1000 |
|  |  |  | RF05L-GJAHR | 2024 |
| SAPMF05L | 0700 | X |  |  |
|  |  |  | BDC_CURSOR | BKPF-BELNR |
|  |  |  | BDC_OKCODE | =VK |
| SAPMF05L | 1710 | X |  |  |
|  |  |  | BDC_CURSOR | BKPF-XREF2_HD |
|  |  |  | BDC_OKCODE | =ENTR |
|  |  |  | BKPF-XBLNR | FI1 |
|  |  |  | BKPF-XREF1_HD | XREF1 |
|  |  |  | BKPF-XREF2_HD | XREF2 |
| SAPMF05L | 0700 | X |  |  |
|  |  |  | BDC_CURSOR | BKPF-BELNR |
|  |  |  | BDC_OKCODE | =AE |

Answer (score 0):

I found this example is very simple for understand....

```html
FORM XPTO.

  DATA : lv_bdc_mode TYPE ctu_mode,
         lt_bdcmess  TYPE TABLE OF bdcmsgcoll. "Message table

  CLEAR t_bdcdata.

  " Selection screen
  PERFORM bdc_dynpro      USING 'SAPMF05L' '0100'.
  PERFORM bdc_field       USING 'RF05L-BELNR'  ps_bkpf-belnr.
  PERFORM bdc_field       USING 'RF05L-BUKRS'  ps_bkpf-bukrs.
  PERFORM bdc_field       USING 'RF05L-GJAHR'  ps_bkpf-gjahr.
  PERFORM bdc_field       USING 'BDC_OKCODE'   '/00'.

  " Main screen
  PERFORM bdc_dynpro      USING 'SAPMF05L' '0700'.
  PERFORM bdc_field       USING 'BDC_OKCODE'   '=VK'.         " [Button to reach header]

  " Header Screen
  PERFORM bdc_dynpro      USING 'SAPMF05L' '1710'.
  PERFORM bdc_field       USING 'BKPF-XREF2_HD'   pv_endda.      " Value to be changed
  PERFORM bdc_field       USING 'BDC_OKCODE'   '=ENTR'.          " [Validate button]

  " Main screen
  PERFORM bdc_dynpro      USING 'SAPMF05L' '0700'.
  PERFORM bdc_field       USING 'BDC_OKCODE'   '=AE'.         " [Save button]

  lv_bdc_mode = 'N'. " <== set A in debug to display screen

  CALL TRANSACTION 'FB02'
    USING t_bdcdata
    MODE lv_bdc_mode     " N : Screens not displayed
    UPDATE 'S'           " Save synchronous
    MESSAGES INTO lt_bdcmess.
*   Get all transaction messages into li_bdcmess.

ENDFORM.
```

```html
FORM bdc_dynpro USING pw_prog
                      pw_scr.

  DATA ls_bdcdata TYPE bdcdata.

  ls_bdcdata-program = pw_prog.
  ls_bdcdata-dynpro  = pw_scr.
  ls_bdcdata-dynbegin = 'X'.
  APPEND ls_bdcdata TO t_bdcdata.

ENDFORM.                    "BDC_DYNPRO

FORM bdc_field USING pw_fnam
                     pw_fval.

  DATA ls_bdcdata TYPE bdcdata.

  ls_bdcdata-fnam  = pw_fnam.
  ls_bdcdata-fval  = pw_fval.
  APPEND ls_bdcdata TO t_bdcdata.

ENDFORM.                    "BDC_FIELD
```